# Problems with loading a JSON REST-request into Kendo ui list-view

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I want to load a a get-request into a kendo-ui listview. I can't figure out why the my site won't show any results. I tried the following code with the exact same data the server returned and it works fine, but i can't get the http-request to work. Here is my js code for the viewmodel:

```
var eventsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport:{
    read: {
        url:"https://myurl/incidents",
        dataType: "json"
    }
},
schema: {
data: function(response){return response;}
},
  sort:{field: "id", dir: "desc"}
});


eventsDataSource.read();

var json = eventsDataSource.data().toJSON();



var eventsViewModel ={ events : ko.observableArray(json) };
```

Here is the view i made which shows the data as intenden when i code the data directly into the dataSource :

```
    <div data-role="view" data-layout="layout" id="event-view" data-ko-model="eventsViewModel">         
        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
            <li>Ereignisse
                <ul data-bind="foreach: events">
                    <li>
                            <span style="vertical-align:middle;">
                            <span data-bind="text: id"></span> - <span data-bind="text: title"></span> (<span data-bind="text: status"></span>)
                            <br/>
                            <b data-bind="text:message"></b> 
                        </span> 
                        <div data-bind="if : document">
                            <a data-role="detailbutton" data-icon="right-open"></a> 
                        </div>                          
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And finally the data returned from the server:

```
[{"id":3,"created":1385573907907,"priority":1,"reporter":"Martin","category":"MÃ¤hdrescher","type":"S690","title":"Hangausgleich defekt","message":"MÃ¤hdrescher umgekippt","status":"offen","client":"Bauer","field":"Kaiserslautern - Kohlbach","scenario":0,"document":true,"positionLatitude":49.405703,"positionLongitude":7.423623},
{"id":1,"created":1385739507907,"priority":3,"reporter":"T670-4","category":"MÃ¤hdrescher","type":"T670","title":"Hydraulikdruck unter Minimalwert","message":"Hydraulikdruck unter 200 bar","status":"offen","client":"Meyer","field":"Homburg - Auf der HÃ¶h","scenario":0,"document":false,"positionLatitude":49.342852,"positionLongitude":6.824287},
 {"id":2,"created":1385656707907,"priority":2,"reporter":"Anna","category":"Traktor","type":"9560RT","title":"Kette gerissen","message":"Linke Kette gerissen","status":"offen","client":"Schulze","field":"Kaiserslautern - FeldstraÃŸe","scenario":0,"document":false,"positionLatitude":49.402715,"positionLongitude":7.445082}]
```

I know it's json, but same origin policy shouldn't be a problem since i want to create a mobile app withour an url. Where do i go wrong. Help is strongly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the question of same origin policy, it is not that your HTTP request works but that when you do a `read` you **start** reading but this might take some time. So instead of doing a read, try doing a fetch as follow:

```
var eventsViewModel = null;
eventsDataSource.fetch(function(data) {
    var json = data.toJSON();
    eventsViewModel = { events : ko.observableArray(json) };
});
```

Now, the body of the fetch handler is executed when the read is finished and the data is available.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't a Get-request possible with JSON from a mobile app?